# How difficult is it to find accommodation in South Africa in December / January?

Tags: accommodation, south-africa

I plan to travel to South-Africa at the end of the year (last week of December, first Week of January). I plan to spend more or less two weeks there. My understanding is that this period is really high season. Hence I wonder how difficult it will be to find an accommodation at that period? Are there places that are advised or disadvised?

Comment: I'd advise splitting this into two questions.  As it stands, the second half of your question is far too subjective, as there's no one direct answer as required by Stackexchange rules (see FAQ).  I like it, but perhaps say what you're after - animals, scenery, wine etc, and then ask for which is going to satisfy those requirements.  I've got a ton of information ready when that's done ;)

Comment: OK. I will split it. Here is the first part.

Answer (score 4):

Like anywhere in the world, being somewhere at high season may always put a strain on accommodation.

Most important is the game parks - if you're going to [Kruger](http://www.krugerpark.co.za/) or similar, BOOK IT NOW.  As soon as possible.  With other cities or towns you can almost always find something, and depending what type of traveller you are, could even rough it in a vehicle or camp.  However, you absolutely cannot stay outside of the special camps in Kruger and most game parks, so you'll need to book that now.  I recommend Pretoriuskop rest camp in Kruger - it's easy to get to, and has a lot of drives with plenty of water holes nearby, very well located and reasonably priced.

Otherwise it's just like anywhere else - book ahead of schedule.  I did a big trip in 2005, among other times I've been there, and we booked guest houses 1-2 weeks ahead - in March/April, and had little problem finding places.

Oh, also the mountains - any places in the Drakensberg, you'll want to book ahead of schedule too, as they have limited spaces.  I recommend any of [Giant's Castle](http://www.giants-castle.co.za/), [Dragon's Peak](http://www.dragonpeaks.com/web/home) or [White Mountain](http://www.wheretostay.co.za/whitemountain/) - all have beautiful walks and amazing scenery.